# what should the application behave when a network request has not finished

Tags: android, http, networking, android-asynctask

For example, when I send a http request to the server and before I got the complete response data, I usually show a progress dialog and make it uncancelable. I think this design is not  friendly at all,so I want to make the dialog cancelable, but I find I can cancel the dialog but can not cancel the http request. I send the request in an subclass of AsyncTask, there is no loop in the doInBackgroud() method, so I can not check the cancel property.
Maybe the original design is acceptable?

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks!

Comment: I'd use ExecutorService to do the HTTP request in _another thread_, and when the progress bar is cancelled, you could shut the executor down to cancel the request. Of course this makes things a bit more complicated, but I think the most user friendly approach when dealing with long-running actions is to do them on different threads, not the UI thread.

Comment: @ppeterka : The `doInBackground` method of `AsyncTask` IS run on a separate thread to the UI thread.

Comment: @Squonk Somehow I misinterpreted the part regarding the doInBackground method of the question... I don't know why I didn't recognize the fact that the OP actcually issues the request using that... IMHO, even with this in mind, I'd rather use ExecutorService too, as it provides API to solve this kind of problems via the shutdownNow() function, which stops the running tasks - given that they properly respond to Thread.interrupt(). I'd also use a latch instead of loop polling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ok if you don't cancel the HTTP request when the user presses cancel, as long as it appears to the user as if the operation is cancelled.

Eventually the HTTP request will fail or succeed in the background. Check isCancelled() then, and exit doInBackground() silently.

Comment: It's "usually" okay anyway. Now if the request really does take a long time to complete and/or downloads lots of data and/or otherwise causes a noticeable effect if it's not really cancelled ..

Comment: If the request is simply waiting for the server, it won't have any noticeable effect. However if it must download lots data, that should be re-implemented as a loop.